# unlocking Locked user accounts on Active Directory using Python ldap module

Tags: python, active-directory

I recently implemented password reset on AD using python ldap module.

This involved passing modified attributes in this manner:

add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, "unicodePwd", )]

This worked since the passwords on AD are stored in attribute "unicodePwd".

Now I want to unlock a locked user account but I cannot find the attribute that must be changed to achieve the same.

Could you guys please tell me which attribute I have to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unlock a user, you need to set the `lockoutTime` attribute to 0.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Is there any scenario in which turning off the  ADS_UF_ACCOUNTLOCKED flag in user account control would work?

Comment: As far as I know it has no actual function

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. However at one particular installation, I saw the lockout being reflected in UserAccountContrl, and there was no entry for 'lockoutTime' at all. I thought this might be the case when lockoutDuration is not set. However I have not been able to reproduce that behaviour at all .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to  [userAccountControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) attribute [ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772300%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) flag which allow tu unable a disabled account.

----EDITED------

@Brrian Desmond is true to unlock a user, you need to set the `lockoutTime` attribute to 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
def unlock_account_ad(message):
    c.bind()
    unlock_account = c.extend.microsoft.unlock_account(user='cn=' + message + ', 
                                                 ou=%OU%, dc=%domain%, dc=%DC%')
    c.unbind()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide information/explanation with your answer? You can edit your answer to provide additional details.

Comment: https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/master/ldap3/extend/microsoft/unlockAccount.py

Comment: @Violet that's not a full explanation, and doesn't provide prerequisite things like what LDAP module you're using, what `c` is, etc.  I would say that this isn't an answer with sufficient details as it is (even 2 years later)